Parsing bytes data in Python
I get this **bytes ** data from API:
b'{"response":{"result":
    [{"date":"2024-09-04T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.51},
     {"date":"2024-09-05T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.54},
     {"date":"2024-09-08T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.55}
    ],"total":3}}'

I need to extract the inner result data (date, id, price), preferably to pandas DataFrame.
Any elegant way to do it?

You can parse it as JSON. See the Python json module docs for detail. In case you get this via requests just use .json().

pd.DataFrame(json.loads(data_bytes)['response']['result']), but yes, if you get this via requests, use .json() immediately.


Decide the Byte String: Convert the byte string to a regular string.
Partse the Json Data: use Python's json library to parse the JSOn data from the string.
Extract Data and Create DataFrame: Extract the data from the parsed JSOn and use pandas to create a DataFrame.

I gave you the complete code to do this.
import json
import pandas as pd

# Byte string data
byte_data = b'{"response":{"result":[{"date":"2024-09-04T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.51},{"date":"2024-09-05T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.54},{"date":"2024-09-08T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.55}],"total":3}}'

# Decode byte string to regular string
json_str = byte_data.decode('utf-8')

# Parse the Json data
data = json.loads(json_str)

# Extract the result data
result_data = data['response']['result']

# Create a DataFrame from the result data
df = pd.DataFrame(result_data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)


You're welcome. It's a great pleasure for me to help others

Use decode() to get string from bytes and json.loads() to get dict from string:
import json

raw = b'{"response":{"result":[{"date":"2024-09-04T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.51},{"date":"2024-09-05T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.54},{"date":"2024-09-08T00:00:00","id":1260546,"price":121.55}],"total":3}}'

## data is a normal python dict with your data
data = json.loads(raw.decode())

Then, you can load this dict into dataframe like pd.DataFrame(data)
